# Why errno, when POSIX function indicate error condition by returning -1 or NULL

Tags: c, posix, errno

> When an error occurs in one of the UNIX System functions, a negative value is often returned, and the integer `errno` is set to a value, that gives additional information.
>    -- Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment, section 1.7

This seems weird:

- It introduces coupling between different compilation units of the standard library - error states are not defined in the modules causing them.
- It introduces implementation complexity, because `errno` needs to be thread local.
- It introduces usability complexity because the user needs to check that the original system call is in error, and then check `errno` Which is also another function call.

Why not encode the error states in the return values?

Comment: Pretty safe to assume that this mechanism was invented before threads. Also, to be somewhat pedantic, checking `errno` is not necessarily a function call.

Comment: Also, return values from functions are used to return actual data in many cases.  See [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html).

Comment: `read()` is a bad example as especially here returning `-errno` would work, assuming it returned a `signed` integer, which it doesn't. @AndrewHenle

Comment: @alk Surely [`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) returns `ssize_t`, the signed cousin of `size_t`?

Comment: @alk - OK, but the point that an error code can't in general be separated from valid return values still stands.

Comment: `ssize_t` is not specified to be a `signed`, but just to be capable to hold a value `>= -1`. @unwind Moreover it's POSIX not C.

Comment: @alk: `ssize_t` has to be a signed type to be able to hold negative values. In any case, [POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html) "**`blksize_t`**, **`pid_t`**, and **`ssize_t`** shall be signed integer types".

Comment: @KeithThompson: Well, two lines below it says "*The type ssize_t shall be capable of storing values at least in the range [-1, {SSIZE_MAX}].*".

Comment: @alk: Yes. but you said "`ssize_t` is not specified to be a `signed`". If you mean it's not specified to be type `signed` (i.e., `signed int`) then of course that's true -- but nobody said it was. If you meant that it's not specified to be a signed type, that's incorrect -- it clearly is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For historical reasons mostly.

Notice that in reality, `errno` is *not* an ordinary global variable today (that was the case in the 1980s). It is today (C99, C11...) a macro - usually expanded to some function call, perhaps `__errno()` (and recent C standard *requires* `errno` to be a macro, see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) §7.5); or it might be expanded to some thread local variable, or even some compiler magic.

<sup>`errno`  wants to be a macro for multi-threading needs, so I guess that standards evolved to *require* it to be some macro</sup>

So you should `#include <errno.h>` and use the `errno` macro nearly as if it was some global variable, but knowing that in fact it is not one.

Details are implementation specific. Look inside the source code of your C standard library, e.g. [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) has in [errno/__errno_location.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/errno/__errno_location.c)

```
  int *__errno_location(void)
  {
     return &__pthread_self()->errno_val;
  }
```

and in [include/errno.h](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/include/errno.h) public header:

```
 int *__errno_location(void);
 #define errno (*__errno_location())
```

and GNU libc has something very similar

BTW some system functions do not return an integer (e.g. `mmap`), and some POSIX functions don't indicate errors thru `errno`, e.g. `dlopen` (see `dlerror`). So it would be difficult to guarantee in some standard that every error could be indicated by returned values.

Comment: [**7.5 Errors `<errno.h>`**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) requires that `errno` be a macro, and that suppressing or hiding the macro is undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: So what?

Comment: @alk `errno` is **always** a macro.  Currently, it's qualified by "Very often".  Given who the author of the answer is, I strongly suspect he's aiming for **complete** correctness.

Comment: Ah, I see. Fair enough. @AndrewHenle

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I improved my answer, and took as a compliment the "given who the author is"...

Comment: I suggest mentioning that it's not always possible to represent an error code in the returned value.

Comment: @KeithThompson, like, for an example `malloc()`.

Comment: Side question: Why `errno` a macro?  To support threading issues?

Answer (score 5):

I'll [cite Linus Torvalds](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/errno.html) for this.

> "errno" is one of those few *really* bad stupidities in UNIX. Linux has
>   fixed it, and doesn't use it internally, and never shall. Too bad that
>   user space has to fix up the *correct* error code returning that the
>   kernel does, and turn it into the "errno" stupidity for backwards
>   compatibility.

[...]

> "errno" is one of those fundamentally broken things that should not
>   exist. It was wrong in original UNIX, it's wrong now.

[...]

> The Linux way of returning negative error numbers is much nicer. It's
>   inherently thread-safe, and it has no performance downsides. Of course, it
>   does depend on having enough of a result domain that you can always
>   separate error returns from good returns, but that's true in practice for
>   all system calls.